# load tinyMCE into colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, colorbox

i have this problem: in my site there are textareas with tinymce and i can see all textarea right, but when i open colorbox within textarea, this not inherit tinymce properties.
This is my code to open colorbox:

```
$("#edit_item"+val.iditem).colorbox({
   href: $(this).attr('href'),                     
   data: data,
   onComplete: function(){ setup_tiny(); }  
});
```

and this is my function 'setup_tiny':

```
function setup_tiny(){
    tinyMCE.init({
      mode : "exact",
    elements : "description",        
        width : "40%",        
        height: "200",

        // General options        
        theme: "advanced",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "bullist,numlist,separator,outdent,indent,separator,undo,redo,separator,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "hr,removeformat,separator,sub,sup,separator",
        theme_advanced_buttons4: "",

        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true
   });
}
```

I have just tried this way, after load colorbox:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceFocus', false, 'the_textareas_id_here');                    
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'the_textareas_id_here');
```

but it doesn't work as well.
I have also tried to import tinymce plugin from this site 'http://mktgdept.com/jquery-tinymce-plugin' and also this not work.

How can I load tinymce inside colorbox?
Thanks

Comment: can you describe abit what colorbox does? can you provide a live example like a tinymce fiddle?

Comment: [Here](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/full.php) can you find an example of tinymce. In my site it doesn't work only when i load this plugin on textarea in colorbox.

Comment: no, i do niot want an example of a random tinymce editor, i want a live example of your use case. i suggest you create a fiddle on tinymce fiddle(http://fiddle.tinymce.com/). using this i am able to play with the code and find a solution

Comment: [http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Hzcaab](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Hzcaab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved my issue using the following code:

```
function setup_tiny(textarea_name){      
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "exact",
        elements : textarea_name,                                

        // General options        
        theme: "advanced",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "bullist,numlist,separator,outdent,indent,separator,undo,redo,separator,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "hr,removeformat,separator,sub,sup,separator",
        theme_advanced_buttons4: "",

        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true
   });
}
$("#edit_item"+val.iditem).colorbox({
    href: $(this).attr('href'),                     
    data: data,
    onComplete: function(){                            
        setup_tiny("new_description");
    }                
});
```

In this way i invoke my function 'setup_tiny' with id textarea passed as argument.

Answer (score 1):

Problem might be that your are calling
`$("#edit_item"+val.iditem)` on the hidden textarea element. Tinymce is not the textarea! It is a contenteditable iframe. You may try to do the following:

```
$(tinymce.get('description').getBody()).colorbox({
   href: $(this).attr('href'),                     
   data: data,
   onComplete: function(){ setup_tiny(); }  
});
```

Comment: what does colorbox usually do? maybe you need to adress another html element